# How can I return all data from different scope and receive them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, cheerio

I tried to scrape a website using `Node.JS + Cheerio + Axios`, I've get all the things I need, but the problem is I don't know how to return the data from different scopes to receive it (I can only receive the `url`, not the `data` inside another scope).

The only data I can receive is the `url`, but all the `data` in another scope, I'm quite of can't figure out how to receive it together with the `url`

How's my module work, it scrapes multiple `url`, and inside of each `url` contains things like `title, description, subtitle`, etc, so that's why I have to map 2 times.

Here's my code:

The services that I'm using to scrape:

```
exports.getSlides = async () => {
    const { data } = await client.get("/")

    const $ = cheerio.load(data)
    return $(".MovieListTop .TPostMv")
        .toArray()
        .map((element) => {
            const listItem = $(element)

            const url = listItem.find("a").attr("href")

            axios(url).then((res) => {
                const new$ = cheerio.load(res.data)

                new$(".TpRwCont")
                    .toArray()
                    .map((element) => {
                        const item = new$(element)

                        const title = item.find(".Title").first().text().trim()
                        const subTitle = item.find(".SubTitle").first().text().trim()
                        const description = item.find(".Description").first().text().trim()
                        const time = item.find(".Time").first().text().trim()
                        const date = item.find(".Date").first().text().trim()
                        const view = item.find(".View").first().text().trim()

                        // console.log({ title, subTitle, description, time, date, view })
                        return { data: { title, subTitle, description, time, date, view } }
                    })
            })
            return { url }
        })
}
```

The controller that I'm using to receive the data:

```
const movieServices = require("../services/index")

exports.getSlides = async (req, res, next) => {
    const data = await movie.getSlides()
    try {
        res.json({
            message: "Success",
            data: data,
        })
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
}
```

What I'm expected:

```
{
  "message:": "Success",
  "data": [
    {
      "url": "url1",
      "data": {
        "title": "titleA",
        "subTitle": "subTitleA",
        ...key : value
      }
    },
    {
      "url": "url2",
      "data": {
        "title": "titleB",
        "subTitle": "subTitleB",
        ...key : value
      }
    },
    {
      "url": "url3",
      "data": {
        "title": "titleC",
        "subTitle": "subTitleC"
        ...key : value
      },
      more objects
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Data retrieved asynchronously can be returned via a promise, a callback or an event.  It cannot be returned directly from the parent function because the parent actually returns long before the asynchronous data is event available.  This code would best be rewritten using promises, but you could also use a callback to communicate back the final value.

Comment: Where should I put the callback? Sorry if it's a bad question, I'm kind of brain freeze after writing those above codes.

Comment: What are you trying to return?  An array of objects?

Comment: Yes, it's like the one I'm expected, but I can only return the `url`, so I don't know where to put the callback to draw out the data along with it..

Comment: Right now, it looks like you're producing an array with `$(".MovieListTop .TPostMv").toArray().map(...)` and then within that, producing another array for each element of the previous array with `new$(".TpRwCont").toArray().map(...)`.  So, you could have an array of arrays of objects.  What is the desired end result of all this data you're iterating.  You have a `.map()` inside a `.map()` so that creates an array of arrays.  I'm trying to write an answer, but unsure what the objective of this code is so not sure what to actually make the final result.

Comment: The first `$(".MovieListTop .TPostMv").toArray().map(...)` will produce an array of 16 `url` in it, and I want each of that `url` have its own `data` to come along with it, I don't know right now I'm doing it wrong or not from what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reworked version that uses `async/await` in order to serialize the requests, organize the data and return the data in a promise.  The caller can then use `await` or `.then()` to get the data out of the promise.

I'm not entirely sure I understood what result you wanted because what you described in your question and comments doesn't quite match with what the code produces.  This code gets a top level array of URLs and then for each URL, there is an array of data objects for each newsElement that URL has.  So, there's an array of objects where each object has a url and an array of data.  The data is an array of newsElement objects in the url's page like this:

```
[
    {
      url: url1, 
      data: [
        {
          title: someTitle1, 
          subTitle: someSubTitle1, 
          description: someDescription1, 
          time: someTime1, 
          date: someDate1, 
          view: someView1
        },
        {
          title: someTitle2, 
          subTitle: someSubTitle2, 
          description: someDescription2, 
          time: someTime2, 
          date: someDate2, 
          view: someView2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      url: url2, 
      data: [
        {
          title: someTitle3, 
          subTitle: someSubTitle3, 
          description: someDescription3, 
          time: someTime3, 
          date: someDate3, 
          view: someView3
        },
        {
          title: someTitle4, 
          subTitle: someSubTitle4, 
          description: someDescription4, 
          time: someTime4, 
          date: someDate4, 
          view: someView4
        }
      ]
   },
]
```

And, here's the code:

```
exports.getSlides = async () => {
    const { data } = await client.get("/");
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    const elements = $(".MovieListTop .TPostMv").toArray();
    const results = [];
    for (let element of elements) {
        const listItem = $(element);
        const url = listItem.find("a").attr("href");
        // for each url, we collect an array of objects where
        // each object has title, subTitle, etc.. from a newsElement
        const urlData = [];
        const res = await axios(url);
        const new$ = cheerio.load(res.data);
        const newsElements = new$(".TpRwCont").toArray();
        for (let newsElement of newsElements) {
            const item = new$(newsElement);
            const title = item.find(".Title").first().text().trim()
            const subTitle = item.find(".SubTitle").first().text().trim()
            const description = item.find(".Description").first().text().trim()
            const time = item.find(".Time").first().text().trim()
            const date = item.find(".Date").first().text().trim()
            const view = item.find(".View").first().text().trim()

            // console.log({ title, subTitle, description, time, date, view })
            urlData.push({ title, subTitle, description, time, date, view });
        }
        results.push({ url, data: urlData });
    }
    return results;
}
```

If you want to data collected slightly differently, you should be able to modify this code to change how it organizes the data.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time helping me, I'll try it in another few hours because right now I have to attend school, but before that, I have tried to move the `return {url}` into the latest array, so it's become `data: { title, subTitle, description, time, date, view, url }`, but clearly it does not work, your way seems more reliable than what I'm trying to do, I'll try it later, if there's anything else wrong can I ask you here in the comment a couple of hours later? Thanks again.

Comment: @Bunny - Yes, you can ask in the comments here if something isn't working, but it appears we're not in the same half of the world so I may be asleep.

Comment: It just returns this when I'm getting the response with POSTMAN. `{"message" : "Success", "data" : [ ] }`. I'll try to figure something out.

Comment: @Bunny - What returns that.  You don't show any code that sends a response here so perhaps you're not handling the return from calling `getSlides()` correctly.  Please show ALL the code involved in that request.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've checked and I'm misspell some of the variables, I was able to fix it a few hours ago, and it's worked - your code. But may I ask something, from the code of mine above, if I remove the `return { URL }`, and put it in together with `return { data: { title, subTitle, description, time, date, view, url } }`, is there somehow I can return it again outside of the second `toArray().map()` ?

Comment: @Bunny - You will notice that I do not use `.map()` at all.  That's because it is not promise-aware and thus has complications when using asycnhronous calls inside the callback.  It does not "wait" for an `await` in its callback.  That's why I'm using only a plain `for` loop which is async/await-aware.

Comment: I see, I've tested it a few hours ago, I put `console.log("Run here 1")` with `return({ url })`, and `console.log("Run here 2")` with `return { data: { title, subTitle, description, time, date, view } }` and it will run all the times of `Run here 1` first and then `Run here 2` later, that's when I know why the data return only have an `url` and an empty `data`